# MySQL query, MAX() + GROUP BY + WHERE

Tags: mysql, max, where-clause

How do you get the rows that contain the max value for each grouped set?
I have this mysql

```
SELECT ticketId, version, storeId, `status` FROM ticket where storeId = 1 AND status = 0;
```

and get the result.

[image]

And I want to find the max version in different ticketId, the rows would be

```
ticket | version | storeId | status
---
  1    | 5       | 1       | 0  
  2    | 5       | 1       | 0
```

how the mysql would be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation function `max`:

```
select ticketId,
    max(version),
    storeId,
    `status`
from ticket t
where storeId = 1
    and status = 0
group by ticketId,
    storeId,
    `status`
```

if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, you may use:

```
select ticketId,
    max(version),
    storeId,
    `status`
from ticket t
where storeId = 1
    and status = 0
group by ticketId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `group by` and `max`:

```
SELECT ticketId as ticket, MAX(version) AS version, storeId, `status`
FROM ticket 
WHERE storeId = 1
AND status = 0
GROUP BY ticketId
```